# Return not stopping function

Tags: node.js, soap, return, graphql

I have the following code

```
        insertcontact(root, args) {
        var finalresult = '';
        var soap = require('soap');
        var url = 'http://192.168.100.2/setlead/webservice.asmx?wsdl';
        var soapargs = {
            contacto: args.contacto, token: args.token, PrimeiroNome: args.PrimeiroNome, Apelidos: args.Apelidos, Email: args.Email, Telefone: args.Telefone, Origem: args.Origem
        };
        soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                finalresult = err
                return { contacto: "error cliente" };
            }
            else {
                client.OperationDetail(args, function (err, result) {

                    console.log(result);
                    return { token: result };
                });
            }
        });
        return {
            contacto: args.contacto,
            PrimeiroNome: args.PrimeiroNome,
            token: args.token,
            Apelidos: args.Apelidos,
            Email: args.Email,
            Telefone: args.Telefone,
            Origem: args.Origem
        };
    }
}
```

The operation does not trigger any error and I do receive the result in the console log. But I don't receive the return declared right after that part. The function goes on and I receive the last return declared. Shouldn't it stop at the return result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic mistake in Javascript.
The function will return even before starting to create the *soap* client, because of its async behavior.

That function implementation is not very good as it returns the params whatever the result of the client creation process.

It would be much better to do it like this, with embeded soap args in the return statement if needed, and of course without the last return statement:

```
// ...
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    finalresult = err
    return { contacto: "error cliente" };
  } else {
    client.OperationDetail(args, function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      return {
        token: result,
        soapargs: soapargs
      };
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your returned object in parenthesis like this

```
return ({
        contacto: args.contacto,
        PrimeiroNome: args.PrimeiroNome,
        token: args.token,
        Apelidos: args.Apelidos,
        Email: args.Email,
        Telefone: args.Telefone,
        Origem: args.Origem

    });
```

Comment: I wrapped all my returns in parenthesis, but the behaviour remains the same